# How do I create a Vec<T> where T: Into<_> in Rust?

Tags: rust

This is my example code. I am trying to pass a `Vec<T>` to a function where `T: Into<_>`!

```rust
enum Test {
  FN(Box<dyn Fn()>),
  STR(String),
}

impl<F> From<F> for Test
  where F: Fn() + 'static
{
  fn from(f: F) -> Self {
    Self::FN(Box::new(f))
  }
}

impl From<String> for Test {
  fn from(s: String) -> Self {
    Self::STR(s)
  }
}

fn main() {
  into(vec![
    || println!("func 1"),
    || println!("func 2"),
    String::from("string 1"),
  ]);
}

fn into<T>(v: Vec<T>)
  where T: Into<Test>
{
  for test in v {
    let test = test.into();
    match test {
      Test::FN(func) => func(),
      Test::STR(s) => println!("{}", s),
    }
  }
}
```

The error is at the second closure:

```
expected closure, found a different closure
```

The problem is that Into<_> can't be dyn because it is Sized, so that doesn't work!

I am hoping for an output of:

```
func 1
func 2
string 1
```

Any answers or ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers,
I found my own solution by creating my own `MyInto` trait:

```rust
trait MyInto {
  fn my_into(&self) -> Test;
}

enum Test<'l> {
  FN(&'l dyn Fn()),
  STR(String),
}

impl<F> MyInto for F
  where F: Fn() + 'static
{
  fn my_into(&self) -> Test {
    Test::FN(self)
  }
}

impl MyInto for String {
  fn my_into(&self) -> Test {
    Test::STR(self.to_owned())
  }
}

fn main() {
  into(vec![
    &|| println!("func 1"),
    &|| println!("func 2"),
    &String::from("string 1"),
  ]);
}

fn into(v: Vec<&dyn MyInto>) {
  for test in v {
    let test = test.my_into();
    match test {
      Test::FN(func) => func(),
      Test::STR(s) => println!("{}", s),
    }
  }
}
```

The output is now:

```
func 1
func 2
string 1
```

It is now possible to use the `dyn` in `&dyn MyInto`, because `MyInto` is not `Sized`!

Answer (score 2):

Rust does not generally do type coercion automatically. You've defined your `From` implementations, but nothing is calling them. You'd need to change your function to be more along the lines of

```
fn main() {
  into(vec![
    Test::from(|| println!("func 1")),
    Test::from(|| println!("func 2")),
    Test::from(String::from("string 1")),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you create a `Test` enum does not mean that Rust will reconcile the type of your otherwise heterogenous vector to be `Test`. You must manually instantiate each enum variant (and put a `Box` around your closures):

```
fn main() {
  let x: Vec<Test> = vec![
    Test::FN(Box::new(|| println!("func 1"))),
    Test::FN(Box::new(|| println!("func 2"))),
    Test::STR(String::from("string 1")),
  ];
  into(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is to have a `Vec` of objects all being convertable to test. Yet `Vec` requires objects of the same type:

- each closure has a different type
- String is different from closure types

An example with a `Vec` with elements of the same type could be a `Vec`of just one of your elements:

```
  into(vec![|| println!("func 1")]); 
  into(vec![|| println!("func 2")]);
  into(vec![String::from("string 1")]);
  // each has one element of ONE type, this compiles and runs
```

or a `Vec` of multiple elements of the same type:

```
  into(vec![String::from("string 1"), String::from("string 2")]);
  // each has multiple element of ONE type (String), this compiles and runs
```

To get your example to compile you will have to wrap your items in a wrapper type (e.g. an enum) that implements `Into<Test>`.

Your concrete example already contains such a wrapper type (`Test`) and thus your example unfortunately gets trivial, because if you put already `Test`s in your `Vec` you will not have to call into on them any more (this is shown in the other examples).